# Swift - Using IBOutlet & IBAction in func?

Tags: swift

I work on a counter. I want to stop his work when 60 seconds has passed. For that, I use this code :

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //calling the wait function
    self.callForWait()    
}

func game(){        
    var score : Int = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var afficheurScore: UILabel!

    @IBAction func boutonPlus(sender: UIButton) {

        score = score + 1

        afficheurScore.text = "\(score)"   
    }
}

func callForWait(){
    //setting the delay time 60secs.
    let delay = 60 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        //call the method which have the steps after delay.
        self.stepsAfterDelay()
    }
}

func stepsAfterDelay(){
    //your code after delay takes place here...
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

boutonPlus is a button, when I click on, afficheurScore, a simple label say (number+1).

In my game function, I had this error :

> "Only instance properties can be declared IBOutlet / IBAction"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this code out of the game() function

```swift
    @IBOutlet weak var afficheurScore: UILabel!

    @IBAction func boutonPlus(sender: UIButton) {
        score = score + 1
        afficheurScore.text = "\(score)"

    }
```

So you have it at class level, now they defined **inside** `game()` function

Complete code should be:

```swift
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

  var score : Int = 0

  @IBOutlet weak var afficheurScore: UILabel!

  @IBAction func boutonPlus(sender: UIButton) {
        score = score + 1
        afficheurScore.text = "\(score)"
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //calling the wait function
    self.callForWait()
  }

  func game(){
  }

  func callForWait(){
    //setting the delay time 60secs.
    let delay = 60 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        //call the method which have the steps after delay.
        self.stepsAfterDelay()
    }
  }


  func stepsAfterDelay(){
    //your code after delay takes place here...
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks your response, "Only instance properties can be declared IBOutlet / IBAction" is vanished but I have this problem : score is declared in the function game, IBAction doesn't have access.

Comment: The score var is local to that function. If you need to access the score from anywhere in your class, consider making it an instance class variable (move it away from that function). Updating my code